# Where to read a data folder and configuration file in .DMG Mac OS file?

Tags: macos, path, installation, configuration-files

I am developing an app for Windows and Mac, and I need some help regarding **how should I organize the file structure of my input data (e.g. configuration files)**, so that I can make it easy to use for Mac.

#### Here is how I set it up for Windows:

I have a very simple program that reads some data from the directory `data`. **In Windows I created an `example.exe` and the `data` folder lives next to it**. If the user needs to process more data (that receive in an email), she just needs to put it the file in the folder and double click on `example.exe`.

#### Here is what I have done for Mac Os:

I managed to create the DMG but **I have no idea where to put the data folder**.  Hardcoding another folder (e.g. `HOME` or `Desktop`) works, but it just doesn't feel right.  I thought of having a Button that opens a Dialog to specify the folder, but then I need to **save the path for the next time the user opens the application**. In order to save this path, I need a configuration file or workspace. So, again, I need a path where I can find the configuration file.

What would be the **expected behaviour** from a **Mac usability perspective**, and how I would go about it in terms of directory locations and configuration files?

Comment: This question is being discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366288/7296893), since it's suspect for voting fraud. Please don't upvote the question to _"cancel out"_ the downvotes, since they'll likely get reverted. You're free to vote as you normally would, though.

Comment: [Relevant meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361399/is-it-fine-to-vote-up-down-to-compensate-the-votes-of-others).

Comment: For the record, people might be downvoting this question because it's not showing much research effort. If you can add a sentence or two explaining what you've tried and why that didn't work, it'd help a lot -- that way, we avoid giving you solutions that you already know don't work. (Also, sorry for the one ass abusing the voting system. I promise we're not all like that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say there is nothing wrong with having the data folder live side by side with the executable python script in macOS.

I'm assuming this is a script only with no GUI. If there was a GUI, I say the user should be encouraged to copy the application into /Applications (or ~/Applications), then provide a way for the user to select a "data" folder using a dialog box.

I think the best solution, though, that will work for both Windows and macOS is to allow the data directory's path to be specified as a command-line argument. If none is specified, it can default to ./data

If you want to save the user-specified setting for the path to the data directory, a good, mac-like technique is to use the `defaults` system. You can easily read and write defaults in a script using the `defaults read` and `defaults write` commands. Defaults work using [reverse domain name notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_domain_name_notation) to help ensure that they are unique across all applications.

Lets say your organization is named ttwidgets, if you had a website named ttwidgets.com and this script is named pywidget, you would use the domain `com.ttwidgets.pywidget`.

The syntax to set the default is:

```
% defaults write com.ttwidgets.pywidget datapath /user/specified/path
```

This is then managed by macOS and stored persistently. You can read back the setting if it exists again later using:

```
% defaults read com.ttwidgets.pywidget datapath
/user/specified/path
```

if nothing is set (e.g., first use), you will get an error (and the command returns a non-zero return code:

```
% defaults read com.ttwidgets.pywidget an_unset_variable
2018-04-21 12:08:40.179 defaults[12409:1472790]
The domain/default pair of (com.ttwidgets.pywidget, an_unset_variable) does not exist
% echo $?
1
```

This should provide all the tools necessary to use macOS's built-in preferred method for persistently storing key/value settings for applications.

Comment: Thanks @drootang. This is not an *executable python*, I made my program with Python and then create a  DMG (with pyinstaller). T

Comment: There is a GUI; I though of the dialog option so users can open any folder, but I would like that they do this just the first time they open the program. Normally I would save the path in a configuration file; so the next time the user doesn't have to select it again, but the path is read from the configuration, but I end having the same problem: where do I put the configuration file?

Comment: I edited my response to include a description of macOS `defaults` system

Comment: thanks for your answer, I am still having troubles to put all the pieces together but I do grasp the idea. Nevertheless, you have given me a good starting point for my search: the defaults system. I will have to give a good read to the `defaults` system, my guess is that  python would provide an interface to access this data.

Comment: I will come back to mark your quesitons as an answer once I have managed to put this pieces together. I do have a couple of questions: (1) I am guessing the defaults stored locally and using the reverse domain name notation is just a prevision (as it could be usefult to have in a server, but not necessarily the case), am guessing right? I don't want/need to deal with the app store. (2) Since this is not going to be in the app store, I am also guessing that I can make up any name/domain? Since it is only for local usage, I should not have no troubles.

Comment: Defaults are only stored locally, to my knowledge. Its possible iCloud does some syncing, but its not relevant here. You only need to interact with the local OS. You can make up any name/domain, but you should strive to choose something unique to you. If you don't have a company, perhaps the email address under which you will be distributing it? Or a github URL reversed?